# boxplot doesn't show if plotting 2 plots by subplots matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, boxplot

I'm trying to plot a scatter plot and a box plot side by side by using matplotlib in Python.

The expected result should be the scatter plot on the left side while the box plot on the right side. But my boxplot doesn't display correctly. I got the output as below:

[image]
As shown in the graph, the boxplot was incorrectly shown as an ugly scatter plot. Below please find my code. I would greatly appreciate any thoughts or advice. Thanks for your time.

```
def multiple_plot(X, y, outliers_low, outliers_high,attribute_name):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pylab
    import seaborn as sns
    #plt.scatter(X,y)
    fig,(ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2,sharey=False,sharex=False,figsize=(18,5))
    ax1.set_ylim([outliers_low,outliers_high])
    sns.regplot(x=X,y=y,ax=ax1)
    ax1.set(xlabel=attribute_name)

    sns.boxplot(x=X, y=y,width=0.5, whis=2,ax=ax2)
    ax2.set(xlabel=attribute_name)
    ax2.set(ylabel='NPI');

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: The right plot shows roughly 1000 boxplots. They are so thin they might appear as  lines.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment. It helped me solve my problem.